# VM inaccessible after copying vdi file

Tags: virtualbox

I followed this (http://dirkstrauss.com/moving-virtualbox-vm/) description to relocate my .vdi files.

1. I removed the .vdi file from the Settings/Storage menue.
2. I removed the hard drive from the Virtual Media Manager menue.
3. I copied the .vdi file to the new location.
4. I reconfigured Settings/Storage with the new location.

I could then boot my VM, but when I deleted the original .vdi file from the old location, the Virtual Machine turned "inaccessible". For some strange reason, Virtualbox continues to search for the VM at the old location, though I reconfigured everything with the new location.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to "default VM folder" in the general settings. The following steps solved the issue.

1. Setting the default VM folder correctly.
2. Double clicking (under Windows) the Virtual Machine Definition file in the new folder location.
3. Selecting the .vdi file in the Settings/Storage menue of the respective Virtual Machine.